# Probability of picking a point within a triangle.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Choose a point uniformly at random from the triangle with vertices $(0, 0), (3, 0),$ and $(3, 2)$. Let $(X, Y )$ be the coordinates of the chosen point.

(a). Find the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

(b). Use part $(a)$ to find the density of $X$.

For part (a) I have come up with $y\ge\frac{3x}{2}$ and $x\le\frac{2y}{3}$ in their respective intervals, but I having problems translating this into a c.m.f.. I also think it could be more simple, since the area we need is just half the full box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common distribution of the pair of random variables $(X,Y)$ is uniform over the triangle given in the OP.

As a result

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac13,& \text{ if }& (x,y) \in A\\
0,& \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

where $A$ is as shown below

[image]

The cdf of $X $ at $x$ equals the red surface area times $\frac13$ because $X<x$ if $(X,Y)$ falls in the red triangle. So,

$$F_X(x)=P(X<x)=
\begin{cases}\frac19x^2=\text{ (the red area) }\times \frac13& \text{ if }  0\le x\le 3\\
0,&\text{ if } x<0\\
1,&\text{ if } x \ge 3
\end{cases}.$$

The density of $X$ is then 
$$f_X(x)=\frac{dF_X(x)}{dx}=
\begin{cases}\frac29x& \text{ if }  0\le x\le 3\\
0,&\text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Anton Sherwood: Thx.