# A point in a triangle probability question

Tags: probability, statistics

We have a triangle with coordinates C(0,1),A(0,0) and B(3,0). We choose a point in this triangle and name it $(X,Y)$. What is the distribution of $(X,Y),(X)$ and $(Y)$.

I know that the surface is $3/2$ and is the sample space. I also know that the line from B to C can be given in the equation: $y = 1- \frac{1}{3}x$. But I don't know how to continue from:

$F_x(X) = P(X \leq x) = ???$

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464561/probability-of-picking-a-point-within-a-triangle

Comment: Sketching the region should help. I answered a similar question today -  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350083/choose-a-random-point-in-a-triangle-denote-x-y-is-the-coordinate-a-find-d/4350100#4350100